# Comparison for "ability"

Tags: comparison

How to compare ability between 2 species of an animal?

Can I use just "more"?

> Species A has the ability to maneuver more than species B.

Answer (score 1):

You want to use "more" and then an adjective. In this case, "maneuverable" is the word you'd use.

> Species A **is more maneuverable** than species B.

Or, if you want to emphasize abilities:

> Species A's **abilities make them more maneuverable** than species B.

Or if you have a particular one in mind:

> Species A's **ability to XYZ makes them more maneuverable** than species B.

Answer (score 0):

You could say

Species A has a greater ability to manoeuvre than species B.